# Highchart legend has clipped text

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've a heat map using Highcharts where I'm facing some issues with text clippings.

When I add a label on the colorAxis the text gets clipped:

```
colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
    labels: {
        format: '{value} test test test'
    },
}
```

[image: Highchart heat map]

I've only added the *colorAxis.labels.format* property.

See my example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/7sp8ddpq/1/

It's based/forked on this official Highchart sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/4aqhB/

Comment: You can increase spacingRight param: http://jsfiddle.net/7sp8ddpq/2/

Comment: @SebastianBochan Does not work if the label length is dynamic.

Comment: This is related with known bug, reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3463

Answer (score 1):

HighCharts does have its quirks in the legend layout. You have to explicitly set the width, i.e.

```
    legend: {
        ...
        width: 140,
        ...
    },
```

Comment: What if the label text is dynamic and therefore I cannot know the width beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to make it dynamic, based on a post by TorsteinHonsi on GitHub. The code basically measures the width of the label and redraws the chart. See if it suits your needs.

```
$(function () {

    var leg = 'Whatever';

    var aChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 40,
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
        },
        yAxis: {
            categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            title: null
        },
        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: '#FFFFFF',
            maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            labels: {
                format: '{value} ' + leg,
                style: {
                    textOverflow: "clip",
                    overflow: "visible",
                    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
                }
            },
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 320
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                        this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
            }
        },
        series: [{
                name: 'Sales per employee',
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: 'black',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: 'none'
                    }
                }
            }]

    });

    Highcharts.Legend.prototype.update = function (options) {
        this.options = Highcharts.merge(this.options, options);
        this.chart.isDirtyLegend = true;
        this.chart.isDirtyBox = true;
        this.chart.redraw();
    };

    aChart.legend.update({
        width: 50 + $('.highcharts-axis-labels tspan').outerWidth()
    });
});
```